# Common mode choke selection for 5V 1A smps power supply

Tags: common-mode-choke

I am designing a flyback smps power supply circuit and having trouble deciding the exact common mode choke that I should use. My power supply specs are as follows:

Input - 80-270 VAC 50/60 Hz
Output - 5 VDC 1 A

I found a similar circuit but different output voltage/current:

[image: schematic]

This schematic uses 2x27 mH cmc.

On digikey these are the parameters -

inductance @ frequency

current rating - Is 100 mA enough?

DC resistance -

voltage rating -

What values should I choose? Smaller component is preferred.

Comment: Like you calculated all other components (C2, C7, etc)? Designing a SMPS isn't just copy-pasting an example circuit... Do you have a reference to this circuit?

Comment: @huisman - I felt that power output should be enough to decide the component. Can you please point me in right direction - what should I be considering to calculate the value of cmc to be used? Thanks

Comment: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8038-D.PDF used the RN1140-08/2 made by Schaffner. If you want to copy-paste, make sure to do it **exactly** as shown in this datasheet (assuming you used that) using the **same** components and using the **same board layout**.

Comment: The CM choke is usually present to reduce EMI. What specification of EMI are you aiming for?